# why does get_object_vars return protected properties?

Tags: php

I have used `get_object_vars` for a while now.. It always only returns public properties of an object, but suddenly it also returns protected vars?!? How can that be? It has never done that before

## code

```
print_r($row);
print_r(get_object_vars($row));
```

## returns

```
Data_model_Accounting Object
(
    [get_external:protected] => 1
    [put_external:protected] => 1
    [delete_external:protected] => 1
    [post_class:protected] => 1
    [external_field_const:protected] => Array
        (
            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => LEDGER
                    [1] => DEBTOR_LEDGER
                    [2] => CREDITOR_LEDGER
                    [3] => DEBTOR_INVOICE
                    [4] => CREDITOR_INVOICE
                )

        )

    [external_field_condition_unset:protected] => Array
        (
            [invoice_id_] => Array
                (
                    [type] => Array
                        (
                            [mode] => not_in
                            [values] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => DEBTOR_INVOICE
                                    [1] => CREDITOR_INVOICE
                                )

                        )

                )

            [invoice_time_due] => Array
                (
                    [type] => Array
                        (
                            [mode] => not_in
                            [values] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => DEBTOR_INVOICE
                                    [1] => CREDITOR_INVOICE
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [table:protected] => 
    [predata:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [data:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [external:protected] => 1
    [put_error:protected] => 
    [action_mode:protected] => 
    [Shell:protected] => 
    [access_admin_primary:protected] => 1
    [get_admin_external:protected] => 
    [put_admin_external:protected] => 
    [delete_admin_external:protected] => 
    [id] => 19
    [time] => 1362787200
    [type] => DEBTOR_LEDGER
    [account_id_] => 16000
    [account_name] => Debitor
    [accountoff_id_] => 16000
    [accountoff_name] => Debitor
    [vatcode_name] => 
    [subaccount_id_] => 10
    [subaccount_type] => DEBTOR
    [subaccount_name] => hehe
    [subaccountoff_id_] => 101
    [subaccountoff_type] => DEBTOR
    [subaccountoff_name] => oskel
    [dimension_name] => 
    [dimensionoff_name] => 
    [currency_name] => 
    [invoice_id_] => 
    [invoice_time_due] => 0
    [amount] => -165
    [currency_amount] => -165
    [currency_rate] => 1
)
Array
(
    [table] => 
    [predata] => Array
        (
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
        )

    [external] => 1
    [put_error] => 
    [action_mode] => 
    [Shell] => 
    [access_admin_primary] => 1
    [get_admin_external] => 
    [put_admin_external] => 
    [delete_admin_external] => 
    [id] => 19
    [time] => 1362787200
    [type] => DEBTOR_LEDGER
    [account_id_] => 16000
    [account_name] => Debitor
    [accountoff_id_] => 16000
    [accountoff_name] => Debitor
    [vatcode_name] => 
    [subaccount_id_] => 10
    [subaccount_type] => DEBTOR
    [subaccount_name] => hehe
    [subaccountoff_id_] => 101
    [subaccountoff_type] => DEBTOR
    [subaccountoff_name] => oskel
    [dimension_name] => 
    [dimensionoff_name] => 
    [currency_name] => 
    [invoice_id_] => 
    [invoice_time_due] => 0
    [amount] => -165
    [currency_amount] => -165
    [currency_rate] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, this is not new behaviour, nor behaviour that was beamed into your computer overnight.

From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php):

> Returns an associative array of defined object accessible non-static properties for the specified object in scope.

No mention of access levels.

However, there *is* an undocumented facet that comes down to visibility and scope, reported by a user who left the following comment on the same documentation page:

> Be aware of the fact that this is scope-sensitive. **If you're calling this from an objects own method, then private and protected vars will be outputted as well. Call it from outside the object and the result will most likely be what you want to archive.**

The documentation is your friend. *Use it*.

Comment: ok, but how can you retrieve all public properties in a non-scope-sensitive way?

Comment: @clarkk: Read my _whole_ answer. Not just the first few lines.

Comment: You can break your scope context using a `Closure`. Something like: `$getPublic = function($var) { return get_object_vars($var); } $publicProps = $getPublic($row);`

Comment: @ninsuo, have just tried your example, but apparently still in the same scope.. protected properties is still returned

Comment: `Data_model_Accounting` is an extension of a new instance.. The current object and `Data_model_Accounting` share the same parent but in two different instances/objects.. If that makes sense.. They should not be in the same scope

Answer (score 0):

What version of PHP are you using?

If you are calling get_object_vars inside Data_model_Accounting::method then protected properties should be visible.