# php get_object_vars() cant access private properties in child object

Tags: php, oop

```
class test
{

    private $foo;
    protected $bar;

    public function toarray()
    {
    return get_object_var($this);
    }


    class inheritedTest extends test
    {
    private $baz;
    protected $baf;
    }



    $test=new Test();
    test->toarray(); //does acccess private, protected

    $itest= new inhertiedTest();
    $itest->toArray(); // does access protected but not private
```

if i override `toArray()` and call parent `toArray()` it works ok. It seems like `get_object_var()` works on declare context. In this case `Test` properties are visible. what is happening? how to make it work without overriding `toArray()`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802429/why-does-get-object-vars-return-protected-properties

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from the manual:

> Gets the **accessible** non-static properties of the given object **according to scope**.

(my emphasis)

If you really need access to private vars in a parent class, you'll need to use [reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionobject.php)

**EDIT**

An alternative to edit would be to override toArray() in your child class, and call the parent toArray() through that.

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/7QRCH)

Comment: if it is in scope of `Test` then how `InhertiedTest->toArray()`can access to its protected properties?

Comment: Because the toArray() method is defined in the parent class, but it's being executed simply as a method in InheritedTest.... it's ___inherited___ from Test

Comment: In that case I was expecting that it wont have access to protected properties too, only public.

Comment: No, because in this case when you call it from the child class via parent::toArray() it's running within the scope of the parent

Comment: Retrieves the non-static properties of the object object, **accessible from the context**.  https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.get-object-vars.php